# Turn string with date and time to hh:mm

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a string field in my table with date and time. Like this

20131001094049

Now i have to get the hour and Minute out of this like 09:40.

How can i easily get that?

Comment: I imagine the break of this string is `YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: what's your DBMS as the implementation differ in different DBMSs

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume, based on your string that the format is `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` (Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second). This solution is for `SQL Server`.

Considering that you could go for the poor man fix of string manipulation.

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(RIGHT(20131001094049, 6 ) , 2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT(LEFT(RIGHT(20131001094049, 6 ) , 4),2)
```

Which returns `09:40`

What happens is it takes the original date, `20131001094049`, takes the right six characters `094049` and then the left two `09`. Then it concatenates that to a `:` and then concatenates the resulting string to `04` of the assumed `MM`(Minutes) section.

Answer (score 2):

Because your date and time information is not stored in a standard DateTime format for direct conversion, you will need to rely on string manipulation i.e:

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING('20131001094049', 9, 2) + ':' + 
           SUBSTRING('20131001094049', 11, 2)
```

To return a full DateTime type you could manipulate the whole string and use the `FORMAT` function (available in SQL Server 2012 or greater):

```
DECLARE @dt nvarchar(50), @newdt nvarchar(50)
SET @dt = '20131001094049'

SET @newdt = SUBSTRING(@dt, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@dt, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@dt, 7, 2) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@dt, 9, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@dt, 11, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@dt, 13, 2)
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, @newdt), 'HH:mm')
```

Both will return `09:40`

Comment: I feel the first way is the best way since it requires fewer calculations. I had hoped TSQL had a function to convert un-separated date times to the appropriate format, but alas the only solution to that is your second.

Comment: I have a preference to Substring as well.. much easier to follow. You beat me to it!

Comment: Yes agreed, as part of a `SELECT` statement the first option is easier. If I was writing this as part of a procedure though I possibly would use the second option, especially if I wanted to use the values more than once.

Comment: @logixologist Yes 'SUBSTRING' is my preferred option :)